# Paypal integration in ios business application

Tags: ios, paypal

How to integrate **Paypal** in my business app?

Comment: refer to this https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Comment: I had already try this.But I'm facing "_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane", referenced from: error. I had added all necessary frame works.

Comment: It works fine, please follow step by step. You also have payal client id...

Comment: Follow this link : http://haifa.baluyos.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=64:objective-c-ios-paypal-integration-tutorial&catid=1:programming&Itemid=5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use paypal latest version 1.4.2...and refer demo project from github...its easy...you will get step by step process for integration